# How to initialize an event handler in swift?

Tags: swift, initialization

For the given event handler attribute methods:

```
class AudioServer { 

    var didReceiveData: ((AudioBufferData) -> Void)?

    func websocketCallback(event: WebSocketEvent, client: WebSocket) {
        switch event {
       ..
    }

    func handleMicrophoneData(_ data: AudioBufferData) {
         .. 
    }
```

How can those be set up /initialized?  They are not available yet in the `init()` method so the following most straightforward implementation does not work:

```
init() {
    didReceiveData = { bufferData in
        self.handleMicrophoneData(bufferData)
    }
    self.websocketClient = WebsocketClient(url: Self.WebsocketUrl, callback: self.websocketCallback)
}
```

We get:

> 'self' used in method call 'websocketCallback' before all stored properties are initialized

[image]

So what is a typical mechanism for these initializations?

Comment: I don't understand. Where is this `init` happening? Is it the `init` of `WebsocketClient`? Then why does it do `self.websocketClient`?

Comment: @NewDev oh ur absolutely correct. I put the wrong class name that is actually `AudioServer`. The code snippet is fixed.

Comment: Ok.. But what's the actual issue here? It says that `self` hasn't been initialized, which it hasn't been, because you need to initialize `self.websocketClient` first. Just switch the order and put this higher than `didReceiveData = {...}`